# How can this "nano" error in JavaScript be solved?

Tags: express, couchdb, couchdb-nano

> /home/admin/.pm2/logs/app-error.log last 15 lines: 3|app      |     at
> Object.
> (/home/admin/pcpro-backend/helper/db.helper.js:1:29) 3|app      |
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) 3|app
> |     at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) 3|app      |     at
> Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) 3|app      |
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) 3|app
> |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) 3|app
> |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
> 3|app      |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
> 3|app      |     at Object.
> (/home/admin/pcpro-backend/routes/users.js:4:18) { 3|app      |
> generatedMessage: false, 3|app      |   code: 'ERR_ASSERTION', 3|app
> |   actual: 'undefined', 3|app      |   expected: 'object', 3|app
> |   operator: 'strictEqual' 3|app      | }

app.js

```js
    var fs = require("fs");
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    
    
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    var cors = require('cors');
    
    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var languages = require('./routes/language');
    var formAndTemplates = require('./routes/formAndTemplates');
    var app = express();
    
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    
    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
    
    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/languages', languages);
    app.use('/api/v1/form-template', formAndTemplates);
    
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });
    
    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
    
      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.json(err.message);
    });
    
    module.exports = app;
```

.env

```bash
    COUCHDB_URL=http://admin:somepassword@localhost:5984/
    PORT=3002
    NODE_ENV=local
```

db.helper

```js
    const nano = require('nano')(process.env.COUCHDB_URL);
    
    const getDBInstance = (name) => {
        return nano.db.use(name)
    };
    
    module.exports = {
        getDBInstance
    };
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: There seems to be a lengthy stack trace, but no actual error. Is any more detail available?

Comment: I can only start it this way: COUCHDB_URL=http://admin:pass@127.0.0.1:5984 pm2 start bin/www and it's runing, but have issues with cors errors now :)

Answer (score 1):

`nano.db.use`, much like all nano methods, is asynchronous.  Modern implementations use the [async/await pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), though some people continue to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Try something like this as a sanity check:

```js
const nano = require("nano")("http://user:pass@localhost:5984/");

const getDBInstance = async (name) => nano.db.use(name);

(async () => {
    let db = await getDBInstance("stack");
    let result = await db.info();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 2));
})();
```